# Can't see custom UIImageView tableviewcell from xib

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, xib

i have some data from core data persistent store and i created a custom tableview cell from xib.
I am able to send parameters to my TableViewCell class where i have some methods for set text to some labels but if i set image it doesn't appear.

in my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
[cell setLabelText:[event Name]]; //it works
[cell setTimeText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[event creationDate]]]; //it works
UIImage *thumbImage=event.thumbnail;
[cell setThumbImage:thumbImage]; //nothing appear
```

in my TableViewCell.m

```
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@implementation TableViewCell

- (void)setLabelText:(NSString *)_text;{
    cellText.text = _text;
}

- (void)setTimeText:(NSString *)_text;{
    dataText.text = _text;
}
- (void)setThumbImage:(UIImage *)_EventImage{
    thumbImage.image=_EventImage;
}
```

if i "disable" custom cellview everything perfectly works.
How can i solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Did you by any chance forget to connect the thumbImage to the IBOutlet  in Interface Builder? Also, you checked that the image does contain something, right? :)

Comment: yes i made some breakpoint and _EventImage is != than nil

Comment: event.thumbnail check this is null or not null if thios is null then image is not store here and reassign the image.